# Is it possible to initialize an event without use the function addTo(map) in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

With leaflet, I'm looking for load a layer with the command:

```
customLayer = L.tileLayer.xserver( customLayerUrl, { args }).addTo(map);
```

Fisrt, you will probably notice that I use a custom function (L.tileLayer.xserver) and not the traditional L.tileLayer.

Then, this command returns an image (raster) and also some data in JSON format. My objective is to handle the data to create my own markers, so I don't want draw the image on the map. To do that, I need to wait the end of the downloading of the response.

Therefore, right after I declare a load event like this:  `customLayer.on('load', function() { ... });`

In this function I have my complete data and I can handle them. But, as I use addTo(map) Leaflet draw the layer, and I don't want that.
To try to solve this, I don't use "addTo(map)" but in this case the event 'load' is not anymore tacking into account. So I'm desperate for a way to activate the "load event" without use the addTo(map). Or more generally I want use my data in a L.tileLayer object without drawing the layer.

Is it possible ? Have you got any idea?

Comment: you can fire a event with `customLayer.fire('load')`

Comment: It seems to me that the methode "fire event" allow only to trigger an event. So if I use the couple addEventListenner then I fire the event my callback is called but my data are not already ready.
I try to registerd my callback in the object wich listen the events. And my callback must called only when my data are loaded, not before. I'm looking in leaflet-src.js to find how the events are registered and how they are fire only when the tiles are ready.

Comment: You can send a data object with the fire event. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#evented-fire But I don't know if this helps. Also try to call `.addTo(map)` and in the `load` event you call `map.removeLayer(customlayer)`